# How do I turn down postdoc offer for an industry job?

Tags: job-search, postdocs, industry

So I am in a bit of an unusual situation. I will be graduating this summer and I have been in touch with a professor for a couple of months about postdoc positions in his research group. He encouraged me to write proposals for fellowships to fund my postdoc stint with him. Since these fellowships were very competitive and I stood a low chance of getting them, he promised me a year of funding if none of the fellowships came through. Unfortunately, none of them came through. We talked about the situation last week and he suggested that I join his group and write grant proposals during the first year to fund my second year. Now that seems like a very bad idea to me because I am also supposed to publish papers and plan for what comes after my postdoc. It's also problematic because I am an international student in the USA and I would go out of legal visa status pretty fast if things go bad and I become unemployed after my first year.

I haven't expressed any of these concerns to the professor yet [my fault, I was too shy]. However, I have been applying to industry jobs on the side and was recently made an exciting job offer. I have about a week to sign their papers which I intend to do. My question is, how do I communicate all of this to the professor? He is a very nice guy, seems super helpful and is a big name in the field but going the postdoc route seems risky and stressful at this point.

Comment: You won't be the first student to change your plans based on a job offer. Just let your professor know quickly and professionally, like you would any other potential employer that you are turning down.

Comment: To add to Jake's comment, what you say in your question seems to be very convincing to me. I think the professor would be okay if you politely approach him with your situation.

Comment: If the professor is truly a reasonable guy, he will see your perspective. Don't be shy. In fact, if this is really a nice person, I advise you to keep in touch and somehow collaborating with him professionally. Good advisors are quite rare today.